# Порядок вывода результатов JSON, rankby: DISTANCE

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps-api, javascript

Уважаемые программисты!
Не работает сортировка результатов. Делаю всё по документации, но результаты приходят без учёта параметра **rankby**.
В чём может быть проблема?

```
$(function(){
var moscow_kievskaya = new google.maps.LatLng(55.74143032553972,37.562368359375);

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: moscow_kievskaya,
    zoom: 15
});

var request = {
location: moscow_kievskaya,
radius: '50000',
types: ['subway_station'],
rankby: DISTANCE
};

// далее вывожу данные в div с id="echo"
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(request, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        $('#echo').append(i+'=>{<br />');
        $.each(item, function(i, item){
            $('#echo').append(i+'=>'+item+'<br />');
        })
        $('#echo').append('}<br /><br />');
    })
});
```

});

Ссылки на документацию:
[первая ссылка](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=ru#place_search_requests)
[вторая ссылка](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search?hl=ru#PlaceSearchRequests)

Comment: Да, если что, то это Google Places API...

Comment: @Expert ♦♦   благодарю

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что `DISTANCE` надо заменить на `google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE`, пушо `DISTANCE` еще не проинициализрован и обращение к нему вернет undefined.

Comment: @Fike пробовал, увы... 
Вообще задача заключается в том, чтоб найти ближайшую станцию метро исходя из координат объекта.  
Возможно есть другие способы это сделать?